# On first launch choose language React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and using [I18n](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n) to translate my multi language app according to user choice.

My main goal here is to show screen on first entry to the app that will decide the user language by his choice.

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './login.js';
import Register from './register.js';
import Dashboard from './dashboard.js';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const HAS_LAUNCHED = 'hasLaunched';
const ENGLISH = 'en';
const HEBREW = 'he';

function setAppLaunched(en) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  AsyncStorage.setItem(HAS_LAUNCHED, 'true');
  AsyncStorage.setItem(en ? ENGLISH : HEBREW, 'true');
  navigation.navigate('Login');
}

async function checkIfFirstLaunch() {
  try {
    const hasLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem(HAS_LAUNCHED);
    if (hasLaunched === null) {
      return (
        <View>
            <Text>Choose Language</Text>
            <Button onPress={() => setAppLaunched(false)} title="Hebrew"/>
            <Button onPress={() => setAppLaunched(true)} title="English"/>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(checkIfFirstLaunch());



const Stack = createStackNavigator();




export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

Once `checkIfFirstLaunch()` is triggered `AsyncStorage` saves the user language and remember it to the next times he launches the app.

I have created the syntax that will detect if user launched the app for the first time, but how can I actually show that screen?

How to display first launch screen using functional components?

**EDIT**

```
export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <>
    <CheckIfFirstLaunch/>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}
```

If I try that it returns the following

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
> use an array instead.

Comment: But do you want to show the "choice" screen at the beginning everytime you start your or only when the user has not chosen the language?

Comment: @LuísMestre Only on the first launch, but I can't seem to get this right, maybe I should use `useEffect` hook?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're rendering a Functional Component that you defined as an async function.

Now I don't know if you want to show the "Choice" and the navigation screens at the same time. If you want that, maintain the structure you have and do this.

```
function checkIfFirstLaunch() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

  if (selected) return null;

  const verifyHasLaunched = async () => {
    try {
      const hasLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem(HAS_LAUNCHED);
      setSelected(hasLaunched != null)
    } catch (err) {
      setSelected(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(verifyHasLaunched);

  const selectLaunched = (value) => {
    setAppLaunched(value);
    setSelected(true);
  };

  return (
    <View>
        <Text>Choose Language</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(false)} title="Hebrew"/>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(true)} title="English"/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

If you need to change the render as in render either the "Choose screen" or the Navigation component

Then you have to change both App and checkIfFirstLaunch;

```
function checkIfFirstLaunch({ onSelect }) {

  const selectLaunched = (value) => {
    setAppLaunched(value);
    onSelect();
  };

  return (
    <View>
        <Text>Choose Language</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(false)} title="Hebrew"/>
        <Button onPress={() => selectLaunched(true)} title="English"/>
    </View>
  );
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: false;
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const hasLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem(HAS_LAUNCHED);
      this.setState({ selected: hasLaunched != null })
    } catch (err) {
      // Something went wrong
    }
  }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.selected) return <CheckIfFirstLaunch onSelect={() => this.setState({ selected: true })} />

    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} initialRouteName="Login">
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` - After I click one of the options I receive this error

Comment: What may cause this? by looking at the code, the hooks are inside `App()`.

Comment: Well if that's the case I'm going to transform the App into a class Component

Comment: @Yotam I've change my answer, you'll have to import React from "react"

Comment: Is there a way to do that using functional component only? I'm trying to avoid classes in this project